# excel vba input reference cell into formula and loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have what I thought was a very basic VBA challenge, and have spent hours searching for an answer. Thanks if someone can point me to the right place if already addressed.

I have a formula that is B1 + C1 = D1, and have two 1x5 matrix of data inputs, one for cell B1 and one for cell C1, say [1,2,3,4,5] and [A,B,C,D,E], respectively, in cells (B2:B7) and (C2:C7). I would like to loop through the inputs, such that I get five unique answers [1+A, 2+B, 3+C, 4+D, 5+E], and output those answers in an adjacent 1x5 matrix, say in cells (D2:D7).

Recording a macro does not work here, as it records a copy/paste action that is inflexible for future use (for expanded matrices, other sheet locations, more complex formulas, etc).

Any help much appreciated.

Henry

UPDATE: I believe I need to be using "Do While" or some similar loop code, and additional "For" and "Next" coding.

UPDATE: Here is a step-by-step picture of what I am trying to do with the code:
[step-by-step process results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0WR.png)

Comment: While the recorded macro will not give you the answer, it will give you something to work from. You could then modify it to add in your row-loop, then add in your column loop, then modify it to read from another cell pair to find out how many rows/cols it should process, then... As it stands this will probably get closed because you haven't provided any code at all. The [help] indicates that is a requirement for a good question here on SO.

Comment: You do not need VBA for this at all. You can literally put "=B2+C2" in D2 and fill the equation down to D7. I'm unsure if you did research on this question at all before asking.

Comment: @FreeMan: I have no code to offer because I literally don't know how to write the first piece of loop code, nor do I know how to modify code specified for a specific copy/paste function into a generic sheet reference in order to solicit surgical edits.

Comment: @SalvadorVayshun: I am asking the question to solicit the answer for the proper VBA coding language, not for help in getting the answer. The application of the VBA coding language I am looking for is much more complex than this conceptual example I am giving in my question. Your answer and dismissive response indicate you didn't read or internalize my inquiry, so your feedback is therefore unhelpful.

Comment: @FreeMan and SalvadorVayshun: Saw this response to another question and thought it was appropro:

 
 
"The down votes on this question are aggravating. Its as if people down vote because the question is too elementary, but I remember being new and asking some simple questions too. Lets be supportive of new people, even when they dont know enough to properly ask for what they want. – gbtimmon Jun 8 '16 at 13:38"

Comment: Part of the reason for downvotes is to lock the topic; if it doesn't fit the typical model for inquiry, aka following the guidelines for asking questions, it gets a downvote, particularly if there is no code provided.  I am trying to help in my answer, as well, despite the downvoted question.  In general, it just needs more information.  Many folks remove their downvote if they see more input to the inquiry (not always, though).

Comment: Though I am confused why you need to pull the values up to the second row (in your example picture), I'll give it a go...

Comment: Thanks @Cyril! In short, the simplified formula, C4+D4 in my example, is actually a 10MB model file. C4 represents a financial stock ticker symbol, and D4 represents a commodity futures security. While I can take it from there, I do need help on this simple piece of code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution code:

Sub IterationMacro()

'Declare Variables

```
Dim h, i, j, k As Integer
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myAnswer As String
```

'Set Worksheet

```
Set mySheet = ActiveSheet
```

'Set # of Iterations

```
h = Range("B2").Value
```

'Clear Previous Contents

```
Range("C4:D4").ClearContents
Range("e5:e11").ClearContents
```

'Run Through Loops

```
For i = 5 To h + 4

    For j = 3 To 4
        mySheet.Cells(4, j).Value = mySheet.Cells(i, j).Value
    Next
```

'Calculate Workbook

```
    Calculate
    mySheet.Cells(i, 5).Value = mySheet.Cells(4, 5).Value
Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

If you could draw a table or something to use as an example, it might help.

Assuming I'm undersatnding you, you want to use a formula in D1, and fill down to D7, resulting in showing B+C=D in each row:

```
Range("D1").Formula="=B1+C1" 
Range("D1:D7").Filldown
```

Edit:

Having been given the example image, it looks like you want math to happen in Row 2 (headers in Row 1).  In Row 2 you want to pull up values from Row "i" and add them in Row 2, then paste the answer of that sum in Row "i".

```
Dim i as Integer 'i is the variable for the loop

For i = 3 to 9 'based on the picture, 3 to 9 are the 1 through 7 values

Cells(2,1).Value=Cells(i,1).Value 'pulls up Column A value from the loop to Row 2
Cells(2,2).Value=Cells(i,2).Value 'pulls up Column B value from the loop to Row 2
Cells(2,3).Formula="=A2+B2" 'Sums A2 and B2 into C2
Cells(2,3).Copy Cells(i,3) 'Copies the summed value to Row "i" in Column C

Next i 'Moves to next "i" in the loop
```

Let me know if that is more to your point.

Edit:

With dynamic ranges, you still know your starting point.  You would look at something similar to:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim LR as Long
Dim LC as Long

LR=Cells(Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row
LC=Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 3 to LR 'Still starting at 3, because of the example

Cells(2,1).Value=Cells(i,1).Value 
Cells(2,2).Value=Cells(i,2).Value 
Cells(2,LC+1).Formula="=A2+B2" 'Note the LC+1 goes one row BEYOND the last column
Cells(2,3).Copy Cells(i,LC+1) 

Next i
```

In the last example, you can see syntax for dynamic ranges.  Note that LR and LC are defined outside of the loop and do not change for the duration of the subroutine.

Comment: Sure, happy to try. Here's a visual:

Comment: it looks like I am unable to post a picture or include a table. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should be able to add a picture when you edit your original post/question.  If you are having trouble with the picture, you can add a table similar to adding code (put 4 spaces before you start typing and it breaks out to a grey box, like the code I have already listed in my answer).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the original question. Hope the additional detail helps.

Comment: @hwyche Check now

Comment: Thanks Cyril, I appreciate the effort. This is point I reached as well. I think your mention of "Next i" is a critical inclusion I've missed.

Beyond that, what I'm hoping to do is generalize the code so I don't have to have the rows be 3 through 9, and the columns don't have to be columns 1, 2, and 3. So I think I also need to define columns as a variable.

I think the " Cells(2,3).Formula="=A2+B2" " is extraneous for my needs, as what I only need is the code that says, "retrieve the output from

Comment: If you're looking to generalize, you'll want LR and LC as variables, for last row and last column.  You'll have loops and ranges such as For i = 1 to LR and a range of Range(Cells(i,1),Cells(i,LC)).  This should at least get you to having a more dynamic code.

Comment: Thanks Cyril, I appreciate the effort. This is point where I stalled also. However, there are a few insightful items here I think will be helpful

a) I think your mention of "Next i" is a critical inclusion I've missed.

b) I think the " Cells(i,1).Value " syntax is helpful as well, but not sure how to define the column as a variable, and loop through the two columns _within_ the row loop.

Comment: Knowing that you wanted that type of output, it would be best in the future to give the exact scenario you want, so people can work with you.  In general, when you use the Record Macro section, and it catches the copy/paste jargon, you will see the general syntax.  From there, you can start trying to reverse engineer more general, and oftentimes dynamic, outputs.

Comment: c) Beyond that, what I'm hoping to do is generalize the code so I don't have to have the rows be 3 through 9, and the columns don't have to be columns 1, 2, and 3. So I think I also need to define columns as a variable.

I think the " Cells(2,3).Formula="=A2+B2" " is extraneous for my needs, as what I only need is the code that says, "retrieve the output from the output location, and insert the output given into the matching reference cell"

Any further help on these items is continued to be appreciated!! Thanks again.

Comment: For the sake of the question asked, i think we answered this post.  If you're content with what is here, please mark as answered.  I will put the dynamic references up in the answer, such as listed in one of these comments, before I head off for the night.